# Cell to Char in MATLAB doesn't work

Tags: string, matlab, char, cell

I have used this code to read data from a plaintext file:

```
[race sex age namef] = textread('Fusion.txt', '%s %s %d %s');
```

I convert `race` from `cell` to `char` using: `race = char(race);` to do a string comparison `(if(strcmp(race(k),'W')==1))` and it works as expected. I also need to `namef` to `char` but when I do, MATLAB returns 0 for every element of `namef`.

Here is a sample of my file:

```
W   M   50  00001_930831_fb_a.ppm
W   M   30  00002_930831_fa.ppm
W   M   30  00002_930831_fb.ppm
W   M   30  00002_931230_fa.ppm
W   M   30  00002_931230_fb.ppm
W   M   31  00002_940128_fa.ppm
W   M   31  00002_940128_fb.ppm
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it is not clear whether conversion to `char` is necessary later on. For what you want to do, it is OK to compare to the individual elements of the cells `race` or `namef`:

```
strcmp(race{k}, 'W')
strcmp(named{k}, '00002_930831_fa.ppm')
```

Since `strcmp` operates on `cell` arrays of strings as well, you can also do things such as `strcmp(race, 'W')`.

Comment: thanks, now it works!!! I need to do this: 
imshow(strcat('esame\normalized\normalized\',namef{1}));
before I used namef(1) and not namef{1}
thank you

Answer (score 2):

Since what you're doing should work fine, you're probably missing one thing: the last column in your file has multiple characters, so you need to access the whole row of the resulting string *matrix*, rather than a single element:

```
race = char(race);   %// cell to character array of size [N,1]
namef = char(namef); %// cell to character array of size [N,M], padding added
for k=1:size(race,1)
   condition_col1 = strcmp(race(k),'W')==1;
   condition_col4 = strcmp(strtrim(namef(k,:)),'00002_930831_fa.ppm');
   %// ... code goes here
end
```

If you use `namef(k)`, you'll get the first character of each row, i.e. `'0'`. So `namef(k,:)` is my main point.

Also note that I added `strtrim` to the condition: turning to a character array will pad the fields to the length of the longest element (since matrices have to be rectangular).